# How can you turn on/off bluetooth programatically on .NET CF?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, audio, bluetooth

I write my little MP3 player app. I want to allow the user to chose audio output (speaker/headphone or bluetooth headset). How can I turn on/off the bluetooth capabilities of a Windows Mobile phone programatically? Once the connection with the BT headset is made, how can I get notified when the connection is broken/closed/lost?

(Once BT is on, [this is the way](http://bansky.net/blog/2008/09/redirecting-audio-to-bluetooth-headset/) to redirect audio stream to the BT headset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pinvoke the GetWirelessDevices and ChangeRadioState functions as described in [this](http://www.teksoftco.com/articles/article%20007/radiodevices.htm) article.

Comment: This link is no longer available . i also need help in automatically disabling and enabling the Bluetooth using a Toggle Button

Comment: Try this link instead: https://web.archive.org/web/20100109020523/http://www.teksoftco.com/articles/article%20007/radiodevices.htm